# Should I accept the duplicate if it is really a converse?

Tags: discussion, support, duplicate-answers

I recently asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49459075/use-object-initializer-syntax-with-an-interface). A kind user notified me that it is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15784483/assignment-to-readonly-property-in-initializer-list).

While the two posts are clearly related, and reading the linked question would provide me the necessary insight to answer my own question, I don't think the questions are strictly duplicates. They are converses.

My post was:

> Q: How do I achieve X?
>
> A: With Y

The linked post was:

> Q: What does Y do?
>
> A: It does X

Should I accept the duplicate or not?

In my mind, a user who searches the Stack Overflow database with a similar question may find only my post; he would not be able to search for the other post, because he does not know the answer. So my answer would be "no".

Comment: "a user who searches the StackOverflow database with a similar question may find only my post" -- That isn't necessarily a problem: the user would search, find your post, see the duplicate header, click on the link in it, and find the answer in the duplicate target.

Comment: Aren't duplicates eventually closed?

Comment: Duplicates are closed when made duplicates, but closed doesn't mean deleted. All the information is still there and accessible.

Comment: I don't think this was a duplicate, per the reasons you provided. I wouldn't have known about the existence of that object initializer syntax if it hadn't been for the answer to your question, so I wouldn't have looked for the linked question.

Comment: @Douglas You wouldn't have to look for the other question, though: the link would be right there, at the top of John Wu's question. John Wu's question would work as a signpost, as good duplicates are supposed to do.

Comment: @DavyM I'm pretty sure that duplicates get deleted, not straight away, but over time.

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga Only if users manually delete them (either 10k users or a moderator).

Comment: "*duplicates are questions that ask for a solution to fundamentally identical problems - many questions have similar or identical answers but are not duplicates*" -[Shog9 ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/178816)

Comment: If Y is the *only* way to achieve X then I would say yes, accept the duplicate. However, if there are multiple ways to do X, then do not accent the duplicate, as a valid answer could be something like Z, without ever bringing Y into it. Of course, it is hard for you to know this as you are the one asking the question...

Answer (score 53, accepted):

In my opinion, the general rule for such a case should be not to close as a duplicate.

The main reason for closing as a duplicate is to consolidate knowledge, and get all relevant answers and approaches in one place.

X might be achieved with Y, but there might be alternative ways to achieve X. Those are not valid answers on the duplicate target, since it doesn't ask about achieving X at all. And since the new question is closed, they can't be added to that question. Both questions invite a distinct set of answers.

Comment: This is actually a good reason for not doing it. (A link to the other Q&A as further reading might still be appropriate.)